# How to break a circular depencency and be canonic?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, playframework

I have a circular dependency between 2 models but this is not a real one in the point of view of usage.

- A building is owned by an owner
- A tenant lives in a building

Depending on the type of the user, the relation with the building differs.

```
public enum UserType
{
    TENANT,
    OWNER
}
```

User:

```
public class User extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne
    private Building building;

    private UserType type;
}
```

Building:

```
public class Building extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;
}
```

Is it considered a real circular dependency? How should I avoid that?

**Edit:**

I have dependency injections with Play Framework (using Guice) that also give me headache. The code compiles but it doesn't run.

```
public class BuildingRepository
{
    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private final Finder<Long, Building> find = new Finder<>(Building.class);

    public void save(Building building)
    {
        building.save();
    }

    public void update(Building building)
    {
        building.update();
    }

    public boolean delete(Building building)
    {
        // check if there is tenants in the building
        if (userRepository.countByBuilding(building) > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
      
        return building.delete();
    }

    public List<Building> findFor(User user)
    {
        if (user.getType() == UserType.OWNER)
        {
            return find.query().where()
                .eq("owner.id", user.getId())
                .findList();
        }
   
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

The `UserRepository` uses the `BuildingRepository` but only for a specific type of user.

```
public class UserRepository
{
    @Inject
    private BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

    private final Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<>(User.class);

    public void save(User user)
    {
        user.save();
    }

    public void update(User user)
    {
        user.update();
    }

    public boolean delete(User user)
    {
        if (user.getType() == UserType.OWNER)
        {
            // remove the owner on the buildings
            for (Building building : buildingRepository.findFor(user))
            {
                if (user.equals(building.getOwner()))
                {
                    building.setOwner(null);
                    buildingRepository.update(building);
                }
            }
        }

        return user.delete();
    }

    public int countByBuilding(Building building)
    {
        return find.query().where()
            .eq("building.id", building.getId())
            .eq("status", true)
            .findCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a 'real' circular dependency? Why do you want to avoid it?
Circular dependencies between modules can be problematic, but a circular dependency like this between classes in the same module is OK, I guess.

Comment: A 'real' circular dependency doesn't work, you cannot create one without the other and viceversa. In my case it works, if the user type is correct. I want to avoid it because my framework complains about it. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Did you put these classes in different jars? Yeah, then it won't compile. Why did you put them in different jars? Do you plan on reusing one separately from the other?

Comment: No they are in the same package. I plan to use a front-end in Angular and it also complains about it (as a warning).
Another thing is that I use dependency injection (with Play Framework) and it makes it impossible to compile.

Comment: Ah, probably in the JSON serialization. Let me formulate an answer.

Comment: I also make dependecy injections.

Comment: Have you considered creating `Tenant` and `Owner` by extending `User`?

Comment: @Marc no but that sounds like a great idea :)

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes probably from the JSON serialization. If you use these objects to map directly to json, there's nothing stopping from adding the building of an owner as the building of the tenant class. Which makes sense, if the owner lives in his own building. You could theoretically end up with a structure:

```
{
  user: {
    building: {
      owner: {
        building: {
          owner: {    
            building: {
              owner: {
                ...
}
```

You can fix the JSON recursion by not serializing the owner of the building recursively.

```
public class Building extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private User owner;
}
```

For cases that you actually need the owner information, you can create DTO classes to include just the information you need:

```
public class BuildingDTO
{
    private String ownerName;
}
```

**Edit:**

To fix the cycle in the repositories, you could do something like this:

```
public class SafeDeleteService
{
    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Inject
    private BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

    public boolean safeDelete(User user)
    {
        if (user.getType() == UserType.OWNER)
        {
            // remove the owner on the buildings
            for (Building building : buildingRepository.findFor(user))
            {
                if (user.equals(building.getOwner()))
                {
                    building.setOwner(null);
                    buildingRepository.update(building);
                }
            }
        }

        return userRepository.unsafeDelete(user);
    }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    public boolean unsafeDelete(User user)
    {
        return user.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: The main issue is that to perform query, I use a repository service. Services are injected to each other leading to a circual dependency error.
Using separate models for tenant and owner should fix this I guess.

Comment: Services injected to each other? Can you show that? I think you should have a BuildingRepository and a UserRepository, and maybe a UserManagementService and a HousingManagementService, but these services should not be linked to each other.

Comment: I have to think more deeply about it... Thanks!

Comment: I need to inject a UserRepository in the BuildingRepository to do some check on the tenants of the building. I need to inject the BuildingRepository in the UserRepository to filter results. This is examples but there is many cases.

Comment: If you put the delete method in another class (a Domain Service) that has access to both the BuildingRepository and the UserRepository, the cycle is broken. The delete in UserRepository then just does user.delete(), which is a bit more dangerous.